# assign templates to "__Base template" through coding?

Tags: c#, sitecore

I am creating an `TemplateItem[TempA]` programmatically as follows. I have to assign Some more templates to `__Base template` for the `TemplateItem[TempA]`. For an item we can create as follows:

```cs
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item myItem = CatalogHome.Add(txtBrandName.Text, sample);
var baseProductTemplateIds = SelectedProductItems.Select(item => item.ID.ToString());
var fieldValue = string.Join("|", baseProductTemplateIds);
using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
    try
    {
        myItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
        myItem["__Base Template"] = fieldValue;
        myItem.Editing.EndEdit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Exception Message: " + ex.Message, this);
    }
}
```

The above is only for an Item. How to achieve the same for `TemplateItem`? Creating `templateItem` as follows:

```cs
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item CatalogHome = master.GetItem("/sitecore/templates/User Defined/SC-DW Data/Brand Custom/Product");
Sitecore.Data.Items.TemplateItem sample = master.Templates["System/Templates/Template"];
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item myItem = CatalogHome.Add(txtBrandName.Text, sample);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TemplateItem` class has `InnerItem` property which references to the original `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item` in the tree. You can edit this item and the template will be updated:

```cs
Sitecore.Data.Items.TemplateItem sample = master.Templates["System/Templates/Template"];
sample.InnerItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
sample.InnerItem["__Base Template"] = fieldValue;
sample.InnerItem.Editing.EndEdit();
```